# merge() missing 1 required positional argument: 'right'

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing a tutorial and I have a problem:
**My code:**

```
import html5lib 
import quandl
import pandas as pd
import pickle

pd.read_html("https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states")
main_df = pd.DataFrame()
fiddy_states = pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')
for abbv in fiddy_states[0][0][1:]:
    query = "FMAC/HPI_"+str(abbv)
    df = quandl.get(query)

if main_df.empty:
    main_df = df 
else:
    main_df = pd.merge (main_df , df, how = "right")
print(pd.merge(main_df))
```

**and my error is**:

```
TypeError: merge() missing 1 required positional argument: 'right'
```

what's wrong?

Comment: pd.merge (main_df , df, how = "right") is missing one argument 'on'.

Comment: pd.merge (main_df , df, how = "right", on = 'something')

Comment: `merge` is a dataframe method and should be used like this: `main_df.merge(df, how="right")`

Comment: thanks, that helped

Answer (score 3):

```
main_df.merge(df, how = "right")
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
main_df = pd.merge (main_df , df, how = "right")
```

with

```
main_df = main_df.merge(df, how = "right")
```

There is no need to specify main_df inside the parenthesis when you are calling the function. You specify the first(left) dataframe outside the parenthesis, and the second one(right) inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

`right` basically means the dataframe on the right side. In your case you should remove `df` from merge command and then choose `right=df`. This will work.